# ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory extracted files takes subfolder name in the file names

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, oculus

In my code, after downloading a zip file I'm extracting it using `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` it works normally in the editor and when I build it on UWP platform(normal file name after extraction - `image123.jpg`), but in android platform for Oculus-Quest
files are getting extracted with the folder name In it like `Images\image123.jpg` and it skips the subfolder.
I read somewhere that it may be because of the forward slash, but it's a zip file, and even where the zip file is made I tried changing all slashes to / backward slash.

Comment: I see no folder name in `image123.jpg`.

Comment: I see that file `image123.jpg` is in folder `Images`.

Comment: yes `image123` should be extracted in the folder name `Images`, but I get the extracted file name as `Image\image123.jpg`

Comment: Impossible. File names cannot contain a `\\`. Please tell full paths.

Comment: Full path of zip file - `application.temporaryCachePath/Images.zip`    , After extracting the zip - `application.temporaryCachePath/Images/Images\image123.jpg` in which `Images\image123.jpg` is the file name

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses `/` in paths because `\` is used for something else.
Swap the `\` in your code to `/` and it should work.

Comment: already doing this while zipping files into the zip file, but no luck :(